# PHP Prepared MySQL statments have started adding quote marks

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I have been using prepared statements for a while and for a number of projects and it has been a really good clean way to interact with the MySQL db, but today I have come across a strange problems.

My prepared statement has started adding extra ' to the sql statements and for the life of me I have no idea why...

so here is the code:

```
<?php

    $sortby="ORDER BY submit_date DESC";
    $offset = 3;

    $sql = "SELECT img_id, img_name, submit_date FROM tbl_images WHERE img_active='y' :sortby LIMIT :offset, 9";

    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":sortby", $sortby, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":offset", $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

so the above doesnt return anything, so looking at the database logs, this is what the query looks like

```
SELECT img_id, img_name, submit_date FROM tbl_images WHERE img_active='y' 'ORDER BY submit_date DESC' LIMIT 3, 9
```

it seems to have put an extra set of ' ' around the "ORDER BY submit_date DESC", but yet hasnt around the offset?

Can anyone spot the problem as its driving me mad :)

Thank you in advance!

Solution, thanks to the guys that posted, you were correct, I split the fields out to parts and works like a charm. Code solution below:

```
<?php

    $sortfield="submit_date";
    $sortway="DESC"
    $offset = 3;

    $sql = "SELECT img_id, img_name, submit_date FROM tbl_images WHERE img_active='y' ORDER BY :sortfield :sortway LIMIT :offset, 9";

    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":sortfield", $sortfield, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":sortway", $sortway, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":offset", $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to be using a bound parameter to define the entire ORDER BY clause.

Comment: i think it is default but correct me someone if i think wrong

Comment: How is that generated query not a syntax error?

Comment: @andrewsi - Didnt think of that, but it should still work though shouldnt it?

Comment: I think you can only use them for variables - if it's going to quote the values in the finished query, then you can't use them for table names, column names, or for parts of the query like ORDER BY.

Comment: @andrewsi thanks for that :) added the solution above, you were correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for [`mysqli_stmt::prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php):

> The markers are legal only in certain places in SQL statements. For example, they are allowed in the VALUES() list of an INSERT statement (to specify column values for a row), or in a comparison with a column in a WHERE clause to specify a comparison value.

Basically, anything structural to the query is not allowed to be a bound parameter. Only data can be sent in this way.

PDO's prepared statements work in effectively the same way. In your case, however, PDO is a bit stupid, because it's running in "emulate prepares" mode (which is the default, but you should turn it off to get the most from PDO). It basically does all the substitution itself, rather than sending the query and the data to the server separately. It sees that the data is a string and thinks "aha, a string: I need to put quotes around this." You therefore end up with your malformed query.

The solution is not to build up structural parts of your query with bound parameters. Either substitute them in yourself with concatenation, or (and this is better) have alternative query strings for different settings. This is the most secure way: anything involving concatenation is a recipe for insecurity.

Oh, and turn PDO emulate prepares off!

Comment: Thanks for this :) will look at turning off emulate prepares :) thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

With PDO you shouldn't use prepared statement binding variable substitution outside the WHERE clause or an ON clause. If you do they--any string--will get quoted (as they should).  While the $offset integer binding might work, you shouldn't do it.  You should just substitute the value with a string (after comparing it to a whitelist array of valid values).

```
  $sql = "SELECT img_id, img_name, submit_date FROM tbl_images WHERE img_active='y' $sortby LIMIT $offset, 9";
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to string interpolate `$sortby`, rather than bind it as an escaped and quoted SQL literal.

(But take care not to interpolate untrusted SQL fragments!)

Parameter binding is for the substitution of *literal values* into queries, by which we usually mean plain numbers or strings.  Parameters are not for SQL identifiers (like table or column names) nor for syntactic elements.

PDO is interpreting `$sortby` as a literal string, which is what you asked it to do:

```
SELECT ... WHERE image_active='y' 'literal string substituted here' ...
```

You're certainly generating a syntax error with that query.

Confusing matters somewhat is that MySQL *does* allow placeholders for arguments to LIMIT clauses.  This is quite convenient, but surprising to those familiar with other RDBMSs.